# understanding how zip in range-v3 works

Tags: c++, iterator, range-v3

I am trying to understand how ranges::views::zip works in range-v3. I understand that it is a range that allows to iterate on several ranges in one single loop by creating a tuple of the elements in different ranges.

```
std::vector<int> v1 = {0, 1, 2};
std::vector<char> v2 = {'a', 'b', 'c'};


auto zip = ranges::views::zip(v1,v2);
// zip(v1,v2) = [(0,a), (1,b), (2,c)]

ranges::actions::sort(zip);
std::sort(std::begin(zip), std::end(zip));
```

The sort using `ranges::actions` works fine but `std::sort` doesnt compile and gives the following error

```
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:151: error: no matching function for call to ‘swap(concepts::return_t<ranges::common_pair<int&, double&>, void>, concepts::return_t<ranges::common_pair<int&, double&>, void>)’
  151 |       swap(*__a, *__b);
      |       ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Why is this happening?

I have also tried to remove elements in both containers at the same time. `ranges::actions::unique` doesn't compile with the following error:

```
/home/jjcasmar/projects/cpfsofaplugin/src/CPFSofaPlugin/minimalExample.cpp:27: error: no match for call to ‘(const ranges::actions::action_closure<ranges::actions::unique_fn>) (ranges::zip_view<ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, ranges::ref_view<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >&)’
   27 |     ranges::actions::unique(v1Andv2);
      |                                    ^
```

but `auto lastIt = std::unique(std::begin(v1Andv2), std::end(v1Andv2))` compiles find, although I dont know how to get the internal iterators of the zip to be able to erase past the end elements.

I dont really understand how this works under the hood and why in some cases std algorithms work fine but in some cases it doesn't. Can someone give some explanation about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the types:

```
auto zip = ranges::views::zip(v1, v2);
// ranges::zip_view<
//   ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>
//   ranges::ref_view<std::vector<char>>
// >

auto begin = std::begin(zip);
// ranges::basic_iterator<
//   ranges::iter_zip_with_view<
//     ranges::detail::indirect_zip_fn_,
//     ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>,
//     ranges::ref_view<std::vector<char>>
//   >::cursor<false>
// >

using traits = std::iterator_traits<decltype(begin)>;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<traits::value_type, std::pair<int, char>>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<traits::reference, ranges::common_pair<int&, char&>>);
```

The `value_type` type is a `std::pair` of values. The `reference` type is a `ranges::common_pair` of references.

`std::sort` uses `std::iter_swap` which is specified in terms of dereferencing the iterators and calling `std::swap`. So `std::sort` will try to swap two `ranges::common_pair` of references. On the other hand, `ranges::actions::sort` uses `ranges::iter_swap` which is customized to handle pairs and tuples of references.

Pairs and tuples of references are/were second class citizens in the standard library.

`ranges::actions::unique` requires an erasable range which evidently this does not satisfy.

**Added**

The documentation for range-v3 *is* sparse. To find information such as the above, there is of course looking at the source for range-v3,  quick experimentation on godbolt.org (range-v3 is an available library), and "standard" C++ tricks to find the type of a variable (e.g., calling a function template which is declared but not defined, with the variable's type as the template argument, and seeing which instantiation is called).

To comment more on `unique`, `ranges::action::unique` does not return an iterator. It erases the non-unique elements and returns a range (see [the source](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/action/unique.hpp#L47-L57)). In part of the compiler error which was omitted, the error references the fact that the range is not erasable (buried in a huge error).

`ranges::unique` returns an iterator and can be called without error. This is a `basic_iterator<...>`. One option is to use `ranges::distance` to find the distance from the `begin` zip iterator and use this to get the underlying iterator:

```
auto zip_uniq_iter = ranges::unique(zip);
auto first_uniq_iter = std::next(v1.begin(), ranges::distance(ranges::begin(zip), zip_uniq_iter));
```

Comment: I understand I cant erase elements from a view. But I can use std::unique which returns an iterator. If I use it with a zip view, I get an iterator which I guess internally must have iterators to v1 and v2 ranges, no? How can I get them? Finally, how can I find this information you provided? Documentation of range-v3 looks really weird

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use std::sort on views.
But you can transform your view to a vector and then it works:
https://godbolt.org/z/_FvCdD

I can recommend the following sites for more information on ranges:

https://www.walletfox.com/course/quickref_range_v3.php
https://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2019/01/20/cpp-code-samples-before-and-after-ranges/

Comment: This solution requires the double memory. Ranges provides sort for views

Comment: Oh man - of course you can use ranges::actions::sort(zip). But you asked why std::sort did not compile...